# Changing HTTP header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http-headers

I am trying to communicate with a RESTful service in Rails. It can return data in different formats, json and xml. Is there a specific way that I can get the data type that I want.

The service mentions that ACCEPT needs to be set in HTTP header. I am not sure how to do that in Ruby.

Currently I'm doing this for get

```
response = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( <url> ) )
```

I have no idea on how to change the header information for this call. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also URL is composed of path and query.

`<domain>/<path>?<query>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got it working this way

```
uri = URI( <domain>:<port>/<path> )
params = { <query_hash> }
headers = { <header_hash> }

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
request.set_form_data( params )
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body , headers)
response = http.request(request)
```

where `query_hash` is all the queries in hash ex: `{ "q" => "cats" }`
similarly for `header_hash` ex: `{ "ACCEPT" => "text/json" }`

Comment: +1 Really nice, that should be more upvoted. It was hard to find a simple working example of it.

Answer (score 0):

First off you'll have to create http session object:

```
http_session = Net::HTTP.new( URI.parse('...').to_s, 80 )
```

Then you can define http headers as a hash and pass it to get method as 2nd argument:

```
http_session.get('/resources', {'Accept' => 'application/xml+xhtml'})
```

Comment: Say my url is
`http://desktop.domain.com:28880/random/path?something=other`

It throws an error when I tried the first step.. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: In first step you have to pass domain only. No path, no query. So you'll have to strip it down to the form of 'http://domain.tld'